# Send message with aiogram

Tags: python, bots

I want send message when user use key but when I write smthg or command /start or /help bot send
(hi there)
always, what need change to take correct answer from bot?

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def send_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'hi there', entities=greet_kb,)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hi!\nI'm EchoBot!\nPowered by aiogram.")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to move two functional locations because the code is read and run from top to bottom.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hi!\nI'm EchoBot!\nPowered by aiogram.")

@dp.message_handler()
async def send_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'hi there', entities=greet_kb,)
```